# singleton - init not called

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, companion-object

I want to create a singleton in Kotlin so I made a companion object like this:

```
companion object { 
    val INSTANCE = MessagesManager()
}
```

There is something I want to do in its constructor so I wrote some code in the init function but it never runs if I don't use the Singleton.
I also tried to use the JVMField annotation but it doesn't work.
I want the init run would run immediately after startup.

Comment: no.. isn't it an initial code for an object? like a constracture?

Comment: `init` (I think it's compiled into static block for JVM) won't be executed until your class is loaded, so it's working as intended.

Comment: So do you want "to create a lazy singleton", or "the init run would run immediately after startup"? Those are opposite. You have the first. To do the second, just access the singleton in your application's/activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the question, it's not a lazy init. I ended up calling it in the Application class.

Answer (score 2):

`init{}` block will be called when the class is loaded.

So, you must access that class at least once after startup.

And, There is more comfortable way to make Singleton in Kotlin, like below.

```
object MessageManager {}
```